# Should there be a css-only tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303842/how-to-make-a-tag-appear-when-you-click-a-checkbox) as an example for some others I have seen in the past, wouldn't it be convenient to have a `css-only` tag to emphasize that the poster does not want a Javascript/jQuery answer? It seems inevitable that these come up, even if it's stated in the question or comments that a css-only solution is preferred/required.

I think it would be quite self explanatory and simply come up as suggestion if you started typing `css` in the tag line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, let's not do that. It will be a meta-tag.

If the OP is not interested in jQuery/JavaScript or other non-sense they should make that clear in their question.

Answers that still ignore that request are eligible for a down vote as they are *not useful*.

Users seeking for a solution that are open for mixed techniques can tag their question as such.